# Creating a custom component for alerts?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm trying develop a custom component like that shown in my mockup. I found an example component on the web (might have been in Sencha's docs), and now I'm trying to adapt it for my purposes.  I have two questions:

- Is this the right approach?
- How do I drive my data dynamically from my AlertStore.  The example was hard-code with a data: [] value.  This can't be bound to a Store?

What I need is like a scrollable list view but with a different type of view.  Sort of like the balloons in Apple's iPhone Messages app.

[image: Component Mockup]

Sample code that I found on the Internet and I'm in the middle of adapting:

```
Ext.define("Sencha.view.ComponentView", {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'custom-component',

    config: {
        xtype: 'container',
        scrollable: true,
        layout: {type: 'vbox', pack: 'start', align: 'stretch'},
        cls: ['view1'],
        data: {
            items: [
                {name: 'Congestion near tunnel', n: 100},
                {name: 'Car fore near exit 10', n: 21},
                {name: 'Broken down vehicle in tunnel', n: 24},
                {name: 'Slow traffic next 20 miles', n: 24},
                {name: 'Drive carefully', n: 26}
            ]
        },
        store: 'AlertStore',

        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(

            '<tpl for="items">',
            '{% if(xindex % this.getPerRow() == 1) {%}',
            '<div class="view-container">',
            '{% } %}',

            '<div class="alert-row">',
            '<div class="name">{[xindex]} - {name}</div>',
            '</div>',

            '{% if(xindex % this.getPerRow() == 0 || xindex == xcount){ %}',
            '</div>',
            '{% } %}',
            '</tpl>',
            {
                getPerRow: function () {
                    return 2;
                }
            })
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);

    }
});
```

Comment: You seem to be on the right track, except that you probably want to extend `Ext.dataview.DataView` rather than `Ext.Component`.  Then you can bind to a store.

Comment: Would you mind giving some feedback on the answers we gave?

Comment: Ok, thanks. The problem in my humble opionion is that your two questions are open (a bit vague?), so it's hard to give precise answers. The first: am I in the right direction? Yes you are. Second: how do I use a store? Check docs! We are not here to do your job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use a [list](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List) and a [css class](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-itemCls) to add [rounded corners](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp) to your list items.

Here is a basic fiddle: http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/vZ4fT/

Comment: When I try to run the fiddle, I get an error message: "Files were failed to be saved"

Comment: Ugh, I've had a hard time with that site lately. If you check out the other links you should be able to get the idea. If not I can try to repost later.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this chat for [this application](http://www.dealersapp.it/) with Sencha Touch 2:

[image]

This is a `list` with an XTemplate. As @kevhender suggested in his comment, you should let your component inherit from `Ext.dataview.DataView` (or `Ext.dataview.List` if you don't need listitems made by more than one component).

Of course you can drive your component with a `store`, checkout Sencha Docs section on [stores](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store). You can basically retrieve your data from a proxy attached to the store, or you can get it from any other source, for example with `Ext.Ajax` or `Ext.data.JsonP`, then use `setData()` on the store. Once you have configured correctly the store the list will automatically update itself when changing its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with from the provided answers.

```
    Ext.define("SF.view.SampleDataView", {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        xtype: 'sample-view',
        id: 'sample-view-id',

        requires: [],

        config: {
            cls: ['class1', 'class2'],

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'dataview',
                    cls: 'myclass',
                    itemTpl: '{name}',
                    store: {
                        fields: ['name'],
                        data: [
                            {name: 'Congestion near tunnel'},
                            {name: 'Broken down vehicle in tunnel'},
                                                                                                {name: 'The conference is over.  See you next year.'},
                        {name: 'Slow traffic next 20 miles'},
                        {name: 'Drive carefully'},
                        {name: 'Congestion near tunnel'},
                        {name: 'Broken down vehicle in tunnel'},
                        {name: 'The conference is over.  See you next year.'},
                        {name: 'Slow traffic next 20 miles'},
                        {name: 'Drive carefully'}
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

I also added some margin and padding to @bwags' css.

```
    .customRound {
        border:2px solid;
        border-radius:25px;
        margin: 30px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: A little childish to downvote me sharing the basic structure of my solution?  It doesn't hurt to throw down breadcrumbs.  I accepted someone else's answer.